# Binary Classification - Separating data by categorical data and creating regression for each group

Tags: logistic, classification, predictive-models, accuracy

My and friend and I are complete beginners to statistical learning and we were playing around with a data set on loan approval using logistic regression. Each data point contains numeric variables like income as well as multiple qualitative variables like education level. I noticed that splitting up the data by the category they belong to for one of the qualitative variables and creating a separate logistic regression for each group improved accuracy. I was wondering if this is a valid technique and could I extend this by grouping the data by combinations of all the possible categories of qualitative data and creating models for each group so each model essentially only has numeric variables as predictors.